# Determine which files are stored in bad sectors

Tags: hard-drive, chkdsk, bad-sectors

I ran CHKDSK last night (log below) and noticed that apparently I have 4 KB of data stored in bad sectors. Is there a way to find out which files are stored in (or at least are partially stored) in those bad sectors?

```
Checking file system on C:
The type of the file system is NTFS.

A disk check has been scheduled.
Windows will now check the disk.                         

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 5)...
  519680 file records processed.                                          File verification completed.
  1795 large file records processed.                                      0 bad file records processed.                                        2 EA records processed.                                              140 reparse records processed.                                       CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 5)...
  673306 index entries processed.                                         Index verification completed.
  0 unindexed files scanned.                                           0 unindexed files recovered.                                       CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 5)...
  519680 file SDs/SIDs processed.                                         Cleaning up 321 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 321 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 321 unused security descriptors.
Security descriptor verification completed.
  76814 data files processed.                                            CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  35149904 USN bytes processed.                                             Usn Journal verification completed.
CHKDSK is verifying file data (stage 4 of 5)...
  519664 files processed.                                                 File data verification completed.
CHKDSK is verifying free space (stage 5 of 5)...
  35264341 free clusters processed.                                         Free space verification is complete.
Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.

 312221695 KB total disk space.
 170332512 KB in 366718 files.
    197720 KB in 76815 indexes.
         4 KB in bad sectors.
    634095 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 141057364 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  78055423 total allocation units on disk.
  35264341 allocation units available on disk.

Internal Info:
00 ee 07 00 96 c4 06 00 aa 08 0c 00 00 00 00 00  ................
09 17 00 00 8c 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  ................
a8 6b 0e 00 50 01 0c 00 50 01 0c 00 00 00 0c 00  .k..P...P.......

Windows has finished checking your disk.
Please wait while your computer restarts.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably haven't lost any data yet, so I don't think there's a point in figuring out which specific files were stored in the bad sectors. When a hard drive detects an anomaly in a sector (read/write speed slower than usual, for example), it will immediately move any data stored there to a sector in a special "reserve" pool. Then, it will mark the problem sector as "bad" to make sure it is never used again. It is only when you exhaust the entire reserve pool that you start losing data.

Rather than trying to figure out which files are in bad sectors, you should **IMMEDIATELY** back up all important data on this drive. Even a single bad sector is a serious issue and could indicate that drive failure is imminent; 4KB of bad sectors is quite substantial. When a sector fails, others often (but not always) will follow. Once you have backed up your data, install a S.M.A.R.T monitoring program (there are many out there; just search Google) and check the bad sector count regularly. If it increases, replace the drive.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've been backing my files up periodically for the past few years so hopefully I shouldn't be too vulnerable. Would bad sectors affect the backup if Norton Ghost has been backing up to an external? Also could you recommend a good utility (or utlities) that would allow me to monitor the overall health of my system and my computer's hardware if possible. Free is preferable but I would be willing to purchase software if the added benefits are significant enough. Thanks!

Comment: @DFrancisFan 4KB translates to about 8 sectors, so at this point you should still have plenty of sectors left in your reserve pool. They shouldn't be affecting your Norton Ghost backups. If you only need a simple program to check your HDD status PassMark's DiskCheckup (http://www.passmark.com/products/diskcheckup.htm) is free for personal use. If you want to monitor your entire system I found HealthMonitor (http://sourceforge.net/projects/healthmonitor/) on sourceforge, but I haven't used it before so I can't say exactly how well it works.

Comment: Also HD Tune (http://www.hdtune.com/) seems like a popular one. It's not free but there's a free trial.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question.  Maybe question should be edited to match the accepted answer and a new question asked

Comment: What if you really  want all files in bad sectors? What if you do have backups, but you want to make a local backup instead of a slow cloud backup? What if you want to delete the files with bad sectors and restore them in new sectors to avoid the bad sectors?